# Definir projeto de construção JRE entrada caminho para 'JavaSE-1.7'

Tags: java, mysql, android

Eu estou tentando fazer uma conexão com banco de dados MySQL, mas quando eu uso `PreparedStatement`, eclipse retorna: `Definir projeto de construção JRE entrada caminho para 'JavaSE-1.7` Sim, eu mudei a versão do compilador para 1.7, mas só funciona com Android 1.5 e 1.6 certo? Como posso ligar a minha base de dados? Este é o meu método real para se conectar:

```
private ArrayList<String> sql = new ArrayList<String>();
private Connection con;
  public String getUsuario(String...parametros) throws SQLException {
            sql.add("SELECT "+parametros[1]+"FROM users WHERE `usuario_id` = "+parametros[0]+";");
               for (String string : sql) {
                try (PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(string);
                        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {
                        while(rs.next()) {
                            System.out.println(rs.getString("usuario_senha"));
                        }
                    }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema não é o `PreparedStatement`porque ele existe no Java 1.6.

O problema é no bloco `try`.
A forma que você está utilizar só existe no Java 1.7.

Você necessita de utilizar a forma tradicional do bloco `try/catch`

```
try{
    PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(string);
} catch(SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Dois comentários importantes. O ramaral tem razão e realmente seu problema é o [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), porém, uma vez que você está abrindo mão dele não se esqueça de fechar o `Statement` e o `ResultSet` em um bloco `finally` (o que o exemplo de código em questão não está fazendo).

Comment: Tem toda a razão! Na implementação total terá de se garantir que, quando houver um erro, os objectos sejam fechados. O código postada foi só para exemplificar o bloco `try/catch`